Identifying unknown lens (Auto Rexar 35mm)
Found an old lens in a thrift shop, marked as "Auto Rexar", made in Japan. Can anyone identify who made it, date of manufacture, specs, or other info. It has a Minolta mount.
Seems to be no reviews, information or any youtube videos about this particular lens





Almost certainly manufactured by Cima... the diamond aperture reference is pretty unique to them. Cimko was their own brand name but they manufactured for many others (Chinon, etc).
Possibly imported by/rebranded for Prinz (US importer/wholesaler); they had trademarked the rexagon and rexatar names... seems too close to be coincidence.
This is a Cima made 28/2.8 branded as a Super-Paragon.

(Yes, the diamond is slightly different... it is the same on the Cima made Chinon lenses.)
Cimko branded lenses may have the symmetrical or the asymmetrical diamond shape.



Thanks, suspected it was Cima.
Not much information online about them.

@sleepy6758, they are about on par with the high quality Tokina lenses of the time...
